# Column String Access for date using day

Tags: python, string, date, pandas

How do I access all the days of the 12 month in a dataset?

The structure of data is:

```
print(df.head(n=1)) Date_Time IPAddress Visitors OS Browser \ 0 2016-10-18 12:57:45 104.236.233.18 1001 Mac OS Google Chrome Browser_Version Location Referrer PageID 0 39.0.2171.95 NaN creditcommerty.in index.php
```

---

Why do the `vdf` index values 6 and 2 in this code:

```
print(vdf['new_day'][6][2])
```

gives this error?

```
print(vdf['new_day'][6][2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-196-c01f93f97338>", line 1, in <module>
print(vdf['new_day'][6][2])
KeyError: 6
```

Comment: You will need to show your data.  Right now there is not enough information given to provide assistance.

Comment: To have a look at the structure of data it is below:
    
    print(df.head(n=1))
    Date_Time       IPAddress  Visitors      OS        Browser  \
    0 2016-10-18 12:57:45  104.236.233.18      1001  Mac OS  Google Chrome   

    Browser_Version Location                     Referrer     PageID  
    0    39.0.2171.95      NaN  http://www.creditcommerty.in/  index.php

Comment: To have a look at the structure of data it is below:
    
    print(df.head(n=1))
    Date_Time       IPAddress  Visitors      OS        Browser  \
    0 2016-10-18 12:57:45  104.236.233.18      1001  Mac OS  Google Chrome   

    Browser_Version Location                     Referrer     PageID  
    0    39.0.2171.95      NaN  http://www.creditcommerty.in/  index.php

Comment: #Get the 6th row and the 2nd two value which is the DAY
    print(df['new_day'][6][2])
    19

    value_list = [12]
    vdf= pd.DataFrame(df[df.month.isin(value_list)])
    print(vdf.head(n=1))
Now when I try to access the DAY part of the dataframe that I did earlier It gives the following error:

Comment: print(vdf['new_day'][6][2])   Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-196-c01f93f97338>", line 1, in <module>
    print(vdf['new_day'][6][2])    
KeyError: 6

Comment: If I try to split it again as per your suggestion I get the following NaN  vdf['new_day'][:][:2].str.split('-')
Out[221]: 
2836   NaN
2837   NaN
Name: new_day, dtype: float64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to present us with the dataset or any appropriate reference. I have no clue as to what your data looks like, and I can only guess. All I can tell you is that

1. The KeyError is thrown because there IS no 7th element in the `"new_day"` column.
2. To access every single data point in your dataframe, simply do `vdf.iloc[:,:]` or `vdf[:][:]`, or `df`. Printing any three of these will return the same.

EDIT: From your comments, it seems like your `new_day` column has lists with three elements, where first is the year, second month, and third day. And you want to return all the days in like a list I assume?

`vdf['new_day'][:][2]` should give you a list of all the day elements.

```
>>> vdf = pd.DataFrame([
[[1,2,3]],
[[4,5,6]],
[[7,8,9]]
])

>> vdf
           0
0  [1, 2, 3]
1  [4, 5, 6]
2  [7, 8, 9]

>>> vdf[0][:][2]
[7, 8, 9]
```

Again, the `KeyError: 6` is thrown because `vdf['new_day'[6]` is not there. Look at your data again. Do you have a 7th row?

Comment: print(df.head(n=1))
            Date_Time       IPAddress  Visitors      OS        Browser  \
0 2016-10-18 12:57:45  104.236.233.18      1001  Mac OS  Google Chrome   

  Browser_Version Location                     Referrer     PageID  \
0    39.0.2171.95      NaN  http://www.puneetmathur.in/  index.php   

     new_date  new_time  year  month         new_day  
0  2016-10-18  12:57:45  2016     10  [2016, 10, 18]

Comment: import datetime
df['new_date'] = [d.date() for d in df['Date_Time']]
df['new_time'] = [d.time() for d in df['Date_Time']]
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['new_date']).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['new_date']).month
print(df['month'])
print(df['year'])

Comment: This works: print(df.new_day)
print(df['new_day'][6][2])
19  I need to access the Day column in new_day

Comment: New_Day looks like this:  print(df.new_day)
0       [2016, 10, 18]
1       [2016, 10, 18]
2       [2016, 10, 18]
3       [2016, 10, 18]
4       [2016, 10, 18]

Comment: After filtering out the 12th month from Month value_list = [12]   vdf= pd.DataFrame(df[df.month.isin(value_list)])                                                                   I try to access the day part of the date it gives error                                              print(vdf['new_day'][6][2])                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):  KeyError: 6

Comment: How do I access the last two DAY value through your suggestion vdf[:][:]?

Comment: Output of vdf using your notation is: print(vdf[:][:].head(n=1))
               Date_Time     IPAddress  Visitors          OS       Browser  \
2836 2016-12-11 01:25:25  66.102.8.217      3955  Search Bot  Apple Safari   

     Browser_Version                Location                     Referrer  \
2836               9  Florida, United States  http://www.puneetmathur.in/   

         PageID    new_date  new_time  year  month         new_day  
2836  index.php  2016-12-11  01:25:25  2016     12  [2016, 12, 11]  
It is new_day the last 2 digits or 11 that I want to access

Comment: Yes Output has a thousands of rows

Comment: I added an : before 2 does this help ?   vdf['new_day'][:][:2]
Out[211]: 
2836    [2016, 12, 11]
2837    [2016, 12, 11]
Name: new_day, dtype: object

Comment: `vdf['new_day']` is the column. `vdf['new_day'][:]` selects ALL the lists in the column. `vdf['new_day'][:][2]` selects the THIRD element of ALL the lists in the column. Hence, `vdf['new_day'][:][1:]` would select SECOND and THIRD elements of ALL the lists in the column. I'm still unsure what value you need exactly. This is a huge mumbo jumbo. Your FIRST element is year, SECOND element is month, and THIRD element is day, no?